# Calculating divergence between joint posterior distributions

Tags: r, distance, mcmc

I wish to calculate the distance between two 3-dimensional posterior distributions. The draws are stored at two 30,000x3 matrices.

So far I have been successful in calculating Total Variation distance between two 2-dimensional posteriors (two 30,000x2 matrices) by splitting the grid into bins. However, I am having trouble calculating the divergence between posteriors with more parameters. Some examples of related distance measures can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4044/measuring-the-distance-between-two-multivariate-distributions).

NOTE: I do not wish to calculate the distance between the marginals (column-wise entries), rather than obtain an overall value after comparing the *joint distributions* in R.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could point out what I am missing here.

EDIT 1: Some example code for calculating Total variation distance between posterior samples stored in two matrices has been added below:

EDIT 2: This is a R question.

```
set.seed(123)
comparison.2D   <- matrix(rnorm(40000*2,0,1),ncol=2)
ground.truth.2D <- matrix(rnorm(40000*2,0,2),ncol=2)

# Function to calculate TVD between matrices with 2 columns:
Total.Variation.Distance.2D<-function(true,      
                                      comparison,
                                      burnin,
                                      window.size){
  # Bandwidth for theta.1.
  my_bw_x<-window.size

  # Bandwidth for theta.2.
  my_bw_y<-window.size

  range_x<-range(c(true[-c(1:burnin),1],comparison[-c(1:burnin),1]))
  range_y<-range(c(true[-c(1:burnin),2],comparison[-c(1:burnin),2]))

  xx <- seq(range_x[1],range_x[2],by=my_bw_x)
  yy <- seq(range_y[1],range_y[2],by=my_bw_y)

  true.pointidxs <- matrix( c( findInterval(true[-c(1:burnin),1], xx), 
                               findInterval(true[-c(1:burnin),2], yy) ), ncol=2)

  comparison.pointidxs <- matrix( c( findInterval(comparison[-c(1:burnin),1], xx), 
                                     findInterval(comparison[-c(1:burnin),2], yy) ), ncol=2)

  # Count the frequencies in the corresponding cells:
  square.mat.dims  <- max(length(xx),nrow=length(yy))
  frequencies.true <- frequencies.comparison <- matrix(0, ncol=square.mat.dims, nrow=square.mat.dims)

  for (i in 1:dim(true.pointidxs)[1]){

    frequencies.true[true.pointidxs[i,1], true.pointidxs[i,2]] <- frequencies.true[true.pointidxs[i,1], 
                                                                                   true.pointidxs[i,2]] + 1
    frequencies.comparison[comparison.pointidxs[i,1], comparison.pointidxs[i,2]] <- frequencies.comparison[comparison.pointidxs[i,1], 
                                                                                                       comparison.pointidxs[i,2]] + 1

  }# End for

  # Normalize frequencies matrix:
  frequencies.true       <- frequencies.true/dim(true.pointidxs)[1]
  frequencies.comparison <- frequencies.comparison/dim(comparison.pointidxs)[1]

  TVD <-0.5*sum(abs(frequencies.comparison-frequencies.true))
  return(TVD)
 }# End function

TVD.2D <- Total.Variation.Distance.2D(true=ground.truth.2D, comparison=comparison.2D,burnin=10000,window.size=0.05)
```